# How come Ceta Disciple is a merfolk?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The Oracle text of [Ceta Disciple](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ceta%20Disciple) marks it as a merfolk, although the [card as printed](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?printed=true&name=Ceta%20Disciple) clearly doesn't say it's a merfolk. How come it's a merfolk?

[image]

The only thing I can think of is there was an errata that turned all wizards into merfolk, although that is surely nonsense given how many wizards there are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

During the [Grand Creature Type Update](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/grand-creature-type-update-2007-09-26), all creatures got a race. Ceta Disciple is even mentioned in that article (but no reason):

> 2) Creatures that lacked races got a race. The vast majority of these are creatures that should be Human but were printed before Mirrodin. In fact, more than half of the cards involved in this update got "Human" added to them. Some cards got other races, like Dryad (Dawnstrider), Dauthi (Dauthi Marauder), Soltari (Soltari Crusader), Thalakos (Thalakos Sentry), Kor (Silkenfist Fighter), Merfolk (Ceta Disciple), and so on.

I guess it just *looks* like a Merfolk? And it's not the only Merfolk in that set:

- [Reef Shaman](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=27158)
- [Tidal Courier](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=27659)
- [Vodalian Mystic](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=26855)
- [Whirlpool Rider](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=27670)

Those cards were all printed as Merfolks. So making Ceta Disciple a Merfolk is certainly not off-theme.

Comment: Reef Shaman also looks to have acquired a profession at the same time, mirroring Ceta Disciple from the other direction